# Style errors with swing: method creates an object but does not assign variable or field

Tags: java, swing, warnings

"*This method creates an object but does not assign this object to any variable or field. This implies that the class operates through side effects in the constructor, which is a bad pattern to use, as it adds unnecessary coupling. Consider pulling the side effect out of the constructor, into a separate method, or into the calling method.*"

This short test program runs as I expected, but I don't know how to address this checkstyle error. Most of the examples of using javax.swing seem to have this structure.

There is also a error causes by EXIT_ON_CLOSE, but without it the process lingers after I close the window and must be force quit.

```
public class GUI implements ActionListener {
private int clicks = 0;
private JLabel label = new JLabel("Clicks=  " + clicks);
private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public GUI() {

    // make a Jbutton named button
    JButton button = new JButton("Click Me");
    button.addActionListener(this);

    // arrange the button and label
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(label);

    // put the panel in a frame
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // EXIT_ON_CLOSE has a style error too. 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Graphical User Interface");
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// update label and number of clicks when button is clicked
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    clicks++;
    label.setText("Clicks=  " + clicks);
}

// This is the code that InteliJ says has bad form.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GUI();
    
} }
```

Comment: _Most of the examples of using javax.swing seem to have this structure_ Have you seen the examples in this tutorial? [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

One bad pattern here is that you are not creating your GUI on Event Dispatch Thread. Not sure if this is related to your problem.. but you should always use EDT to create the GUI in Swing.

EDIT: [take a look here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ButtonDemoProject/src/components/ButtonDemo.java). In the main method you just have "new GUI()" without a reference variable. Writing your app like this example you are not going to use the constructor to create all :)